# java.sql: How to select from different tables in one excel sheet

Tags: java, sql, excel

If there's only one table in an excel sheet, the sql string "`select * from [Sheet1$]`" works well, Sheet1 is the sheet's name.
What if there were two tables(table1 and table2) in Sheet1? the preceding sql just processes the first table, how to get data from table2? I have tried the following:
`select * from [table2$]`
`select * from [Sheet1!table2$]`
`select * from [Sheet1$table2]`
`select * from [Sheet1$table2$]`

 
if java.sql doesn't work with this situation, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial may be help you http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#reading